# Not able to overwrite the file properly through unix script

Tags: shell

Below the script which I am using to overwrite the chk.sas file but unfortunately it's only overwrite the last statement of code **"run;"** in chk.sas file.

```
#!/bin/bash

x=$(pwd)

echo "libname sasdata '$x';" > $x/chk.sas         

echo "proc print data=sasdata.data ;" > $x/chk.sas
echo "run;" > $x/chk.sas
sas chk.sas
exit 0
```

Below is the desired result which I am expecting from the script but I am not sure where I am doing mistake in the script.

```
libname sasdata '/home/usr' ;
proc print data=sasdata.data ; 
run;
```

Thank you in advance for help.

Answer (score 0):

Each time that `>` is used, the previous file is overwritten.  One solution is to use `>>` which means append.  Another solution is to group all the echo commands together and just use `>` once:

```
#!/bin/bash
x=$(pwd)
{
    echo "libname sasdata '$x';"
    echo "proc print data=sasdata.data ;"
    echo "run;"
} > "$x/chk.sas"
sas "$x/chk.sas"
```

#### Notes

1. Unless you specifically want *word splitting* and *pathname expansion*, put shell variables inside double quotes.  Thus, above, we use `"$x/chk.sas"` in place of `$x/chk.sas`.
2. Use `exit 0` if you want the script to return a success exit code even if the sas command failed.  If you omit the `exit` command, the script will exit with the exit code of the last command run (in this case, sas).  This is likely more informative for the whatever code invokes the script.

#### Alternative: here-doc

Another way to write several lines to a file is to use a *here-doc*:

```
#!/bin/bash
x=$(pwd)

cat >"$x/chk.sas" <<EOF
libname sasdata '$x';
proc print data=sasdata.data ;
run;
EOF

sas "$x/chk.sas"
```

For more information, look at the section entitled *Here Documents*  in `man bash`.

Comment: Thank you!! John1024 for your quick help. Now I am able to get the desired result.